# Receiving files using NetworkStream fails RANDOMLY, but always works with Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient

I'm new to network programming and I'm trying to send a file from client to server using NetworkStream (C#).

I think the code below should work, but sometimes (randomly) the receiving end (sever) will just loop forever and the file will not be received (sending appears to work fine).

I've had an assistant look at the code at school and he proposed the following fix/hack: using Thread.Sleep(500) before going into loop that sends file. He failed to explain to me why this works though, he just said it's something that happens and that the original code (without Thread.Sleep(500)) should work fine (which it does, sometimes).

While this hack seems to fix the issue, I'm not happy with it because I don't really understand why it works and now I'm looking for a cleaner/more robust solution to this problem.

Here's my code:

SERVER:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace _003
{
    class server
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //args = ip, port
            try
            {
                TcpListener myTcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(args[0]), int.Parse(args[1]));
                myTcpListener.Start();
                Socket sejaSocket;

                while (true)
                {
                    //čakamo na povezavo iz clienta
                    sejaSocket = myTcpListener.AcceptSocket();
                    if (sejaSocket.Connected)
                    {
                        NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(sejaSocket);
                        StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
                        sWriter.AutoFlush = true;
                        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(stream);

                        FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(@"output.file", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                        long rdby = 0;
                        int len;
                        byte[] buffed = new byte[1024];

                        Console.WriteLine("Prejemam datoteko!");

                        int dolzinaDat = int.Parse(sReader.ReadLine());

                        while (rdby < dolzinaDat)
                        {
                            Console.Write("#");

                            len = stream.Read(buffed, 0, buffed.Length);
                            myFileStream.Write(buffed, 0, len);
                            myFileStream.Flush();
                            rdby += len;

                            Console.WriteLine(dolzinaDat + " " + rdby + " " + len.ToString());
                        };

                        stream.Close();
                        myFileStream.Close();

                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Prenos končan!");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CLIENT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace _003
{
    class client
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //args = ip, port
            try
            {
                TcpClient sejaTcpClient = new TcpClient();
                sejaTcpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(args[0]), int.Parse(args[1]));

                NetworkStream stream = sejaTcpClient.GetStream();
                StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
                sWriter.AutoFlush = true;
                StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(stream);

                FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(@"input.file", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                long rdby = 0;
                int len;
                byte[] buffed = new byte[1024];

                Console.WriteLine("Pošiljam datoteko!");

                long dolzinaDat = myFileStream.Length;
                sWriter.WriteLine(dolzinaDat);

                //UNCOMMENT THIS AND THE CODE WORKS FINE
                //Thread.Sleep(500);

                while (rdby < dolzinaDat)
                {
                    Console.Write("#");

                    len = myFileStream.Read(buffed, 0, buffed.Length);
                    stream.Write(buffed, 0, len);
                    stream.Flush();
                    rdby += len;

                    Console.WriteLine(dolzinaDat + " " + rdby + " " + len.ToString());
                }

                stream.Close();
                myFileStream.Close();

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Prenos končan!");

                Console.WriteLine("Pritisni tipko, da končas");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
                Console.WriteLine("Konec");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Things don't fail randomly :)

Comment: I wouldn't be happy with it either. People who put random sleeps into code are just betraying their ignorance. There is a bug in your code and he should have spotted it. Try another adviser if you can, and avoid this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing using the stream directly, and reading it via a `StreamReader`. The `StreamReader` can buffer reads. That is: it can read more from the file than you expected. This means that the underlying `Stream` can have its read position advanced further than you think.

(The `Sleep` is probably causing the `StreamReader` to timeout during its read, and discover that it has everything it needs. So it returns without advancing the stream beyond the first line)

Either read directly from the underlying stream without using a reader, or always read using the reader. In this case, you'd be better off using a `BinaryReader`, since you want to read binary anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing the length of the file as a new line before sending the contents. StreamReader.ReadLine, however, can read more bytes from the stream that a single line. This is because it does internal buffering. To accurately read a single line it would have to read single bytes from the stream which is an efficiency nightmare.

Use BinaryReader/Writer to transmit the file length as a `long`.